# How can my iphone app send data to the server's php file?

Tags: php, iphone, http, post

the following is the beginning part of my target php file in the server.

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $xmlFile."<br>";
```

Unfortunately nothing is printed on that page in browser.

The following is part of my iphone side programming

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/target.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content- Type"];

NSMutableData *xmlData = [NSMutableData data];
[xmlData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"   encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[xmlData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<Packet xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance iphone_schema.xsd\" xmlns=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/iphone.xsd\">"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[xmlData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<info1>%@<info1>",self.uuid] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//....append xml data strings in the same way
[request setHTTPBody:xmlData];
NSURLConnection *connect = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(connect != nil){
    NSLog(@"valid request");
}
```

the connect object is not nil. But I'm not sure whether the app has sent the request POST message to the php page.

And I wrote some code in that php file to test the connection. It seems nothing is received from the iphone. So what's happening? I test it for already several hours! 
Hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setup your [`NSURLConnection` delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). This will help you better diagnose the issue and see if it's on the iPhone or server side.

Also, if you sending a POST request. So you don't need to read from PHP's input stream. Use the [`$_POST` super global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

You can also ensure your PHP script is correct by sending it a request from the command line. For example `curl` on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

Try ngrep. It might help.

Start by trying to setup [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Then do a

```
brew install ngrep
```

and then

```
sudo ngrep host mywebsite.com port 80
```

This should display the data that's sent and received between the device and the server at mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 0):

$xmlFile = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $xmlFile."
";

This would only echo something if you viewed it from the browser that posted to input, which is not what is happening if your iOS posts to PHP and then you visit the PHP after.

Generally you can't validate it this way at all. You must design a response in PHP and set up your delegate methods to handle whatever the PHP returns.

Such as:

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents("php://input");
if ($xmlFile) {
echo "{\"file\":\"$xmlFile\"}";
}
```

This way you could decode the response in iOS with NSJSONSerializer and view what you posted was the same as what was returned. 
}